# Load additional CSS file through browser add on?

Tags: css, firefox-addon, firebug

Is there a way (eg a firefox add on) that lets you load a CSS file on your hard drive to a site your viewing? Im looking for something similar to firebug but where I can make more complicated changes and refresh the page to see them in action.

Thanks

Comment: If you're on a Mac, you might want to look at [CSSEdit](http://macrabbit.com/cssedit/); it's standalone, rather than a browser extension, but will let you extract, override and examine "live" stylesheets from a site. Saved me from tearing my hair out a lot over the years. Not that you'd know that from looking at my hair.

Comment: How do I get to it? I have the program but I cant find this feature. Thanks

Comment: Open a site in CSSEdit, click the big "Style Sheets" button, choose a sheet to override. From there, you can either download that sheet locally and edit it, or choose a local file to override it with completely. Changes you then make in the editor will be applied "live" to the site. There's good instructions under Help->How To Style Online Web Pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might find https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/ to be helpful. I think was designed more for end users who want to customize the way certain sites look, not for web developers/designers. But I don't see why it couldn't be used that way.

Answer (score 2):

I use this.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/

very useful, and includes the feature you're asking for and also allows you to edit the css live.

Comment: You can add a style sheet but it doesn't stay loaded if you refresh the page, which I need to do a lot for front end development. You can choose the feature 'Persist Features' and it prompts you to load a style sheet on each page, but you still have to manually specify it each time.